# How can i change the maze generate part so the maze will be on the terrain X,Z not Y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The maze is standing up on the terrain:

[image: Maze up]

And i want it to be created:

[image: Maze down]

I changed on my own the GameObject rotation on X to 90
But i did it while the game was running. I want it be like that when it's creating the maze.

This is the Maze class for all settings and generating:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze
{
    //Grid size
    public int width;
    public int height;

    //Store grid
    private bool[,] grid;
    //Generate random directions to move
    private System.Random rg;

    //Start position
    int startX;
    int startY;

    //Public getter
    public bool[,] Grid
    {
        get { return grid; }
    }

    //Constructor of the grid for setting values
    public Maze(int width, int height, System.Random rg)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rg = rg;
    }

    //Generate the grid
    public void Generate()
    {
        grid = new bool[width, height];

        startX = 1;
        startY = 1;

        grid[startX, startY] = true;

        MazeDigger(startX, startY);
    }

    void MazeDigger(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] directions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        //We create random array of directions
        HelpingTools.Shuffle(directions, rg);

        //We are looping over all the directions
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (directions[i] == 1)
            {
                if (y - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y - 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y - 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y - 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 2)
            {
                if (x - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x - 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x - 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x - 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x - 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 3)
            {
                if (x + 2 >= width - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x + 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x + 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x + 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x + 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 4)
            {
                if (y + 2 >= height - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y + 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y + 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y + 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a class that create the array of the random maze:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelpingTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array, System.Random rg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = rg.Next(i, array.Length);

            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];

            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

And this is how i draw the maze:
I can change each cube when instantiating rotation by 90 on the X inside the CreateMaze method but i'm not sure if this is a good solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Maze maze;
    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;

    private GameObject wall;
    private GameObject wallCorner;
    private System.Random mazeRG;
    private GameObject[] bricks;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            mazeWidth++;

        if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
        {
            mazeHeight++;
        }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        GenerateMaze();
    }

    public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        bricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MazeBrick");
        if (bricks.Length > 0)
            DestroyMaze();

        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }

    private void DestroyMaze()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.Length; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(bricks[i]);
        }
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMaze(position, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateMaze(Vector3 position, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        GameObject mazePrefab = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        mazePrefab.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazePrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
        mazePrefab.tag = "MazeBrick";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

And last a script for a button in the inspector:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MazeGenerator))]
public class GenerateButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        MazeGenerator myScript = (MazeGenerator)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Maze"))
        {
            myScript.GenerateMaze();
        }
    }
}
```

While the game is running each time i'm clicking the button in the inspector it's generating a new maze inside the MazeGeneratore script:

```
public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        bricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MazeBrick");
        if (bricks.Length > 0)
            DestroyMaze();

        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }
```

But this create new mazes that are standing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate all the cubes at once, I would rotate the parent object they are all attached to.  I would simply change the rotation of the parent object in the `Start` function of your `MazeGenerator` script, so your `Start` would look like this:

```
void Start ()
{
    mazeRG = new System.Random();

    if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
        mazeWidth++;

    if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
    {
        mazeHeight++;
    }

    maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
    GenerateMaze();
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
}
```

You would, of course, have to do this **after** the maze is generated to make sure the cube positions are correct.  This would set the parent's local rotation to 90 degrees along the X axis.

Hope I could help!

Comment: It's working fine once i'm starting the game the problem is and i forgot to mention in my question is that i have the method GenerateMaze() inside the MazeGenerator script. This method i'm calling from a button in another script the button is in the inspector so after running the game and when i click the button to generate a new maze each time the new mazes are standing again.

Comment: Ah!  Simply add `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)` to the end of the `GenerateMaze` method.  If that doesn't work, I would try running `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)` on the parent object after `GenerateMaze` is called, but the former should work.

Comment: I updated my question with the button code and the problem. I tried to add the localRotation line also inside the GenerateMaze method in the bottom of the method but still it's creating new standing mazes. It's not rotating them again.

Comment: Yes i thought it should be working too. I will try again.

Comment: Oh, I forgot.  You would have to rotate the maze back and forth.  So, add the line `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)` to the beginning of the method and then `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)` at the end :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to create it flat, rather than rotating it into place, change this line (in MazeGenerator::DrawMaze):

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);
```

To:

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
```